# Error in Copying File using C#

Tags: c#, directory, file-copying

I have a .`aspx` page which creates `HTML` file dynamically on `Button click`. The `.html` page gets created successfully but, not able to `copy` the created file to the `destination` using `File.Copy` method.

Code Behind:

```
 protected void btnPublish_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //copy the created file content to destination
         string sourcePath=string.Empty;
         string destiPath = @"d://test//";
        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(hdnPublishPath.Value))
        { 
            sourcePath= hdnPublishPath.Value;
            if (!Directory.Exists(destiPath)) // check if folde exist
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(destiPath); // create folder
                //Directory.Delete(destiPath, true);  // delete folder
            }

            File.Copy(sourcePath, destiPath,true);
        }
    }
```

It gives exception:Directory not found exception.

[image]

The directory gets created on mentioned drive(D:/) but the file copy fails.

**NOTE:** *Currently the path is of "local" but later on this file will be copied to any remote server location*

Comment: Put either `@"d:/test/"` or `"d:\\test\\"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to have the *path and file name* as your destination, not the directory:

```
File.Copy(sourcePath, Path.Combine(destiPath, filename));
```

If you supply only the target directory, you will get the exception that you get now.

Answer (score 2):

There's a *syntax error* in `destiPath`:

```
  ... 
  // That's incorrect:
  // string destiPath = @"d://test//";

  // Should be like this
  string destiPath = @"d:\test\";
  // ... or like that
  string destiPath = "d:\\test\\";
  ...
```

Another issue with `File.Copy`: you should provide *file* names, not *directory* names:

```
  ...
  // Incorrect 
  // File.Copy(sourcePath, destiPath,true);

  // Should be something like
  File.Copy(Path.Combine(sourcePath, "myFile.txt"), Path.Combine(destiPath, "myFile.txt"), true);
```

Comment: Actually it works just as well with forward slashes as with back slashes, the system figures that out.

Comment: @Fredrik Mörk: Yes, both `Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar` and `Path.DirectorySeparatorChar` goes down well; I just wanted to show both formats with `@` and with double slashes `\\`

Answer (score 0):

You need to give path as below as you do not need to add "@" or you can simply write `@"d:/test/"` :-

```
protected void btnPublish_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //copy the created file content to destination
         string sourcePath=string.Empty;
         string destiPath = "d://test//";
        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(hdnPublishPath.Value))
        { 
            sourcePath= hdnPublishPath.Value;
            if (!Directory.Exists(destiPath)) // check if folde exist
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(destiPath); // create folder
                //Directory.Delete(destiPath, true);  // delete folder
            }

            File.Copy(sourcePath, destiPath,true);
        }
    }
```

For more information have a look :-

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe.aspx

Comment: sorry to say @Neel but still gives error:Could not find a part of the path 'd:\test\'.

Comment: The problem is not that the directory does not exist, but that the File.Copy call does not have the target *file name*, but only the target *directory*.